# You will need a new app to open this ms-windows-store in Window 10

Tags: windows, powershell

I performed the following steps:

Right-click the start button, select "Command prompt (Admin)" and type powershell. Then in console:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted

Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
```

But I get the error message

```
'Add-AppxPackage : Deployment failed with HRESULT: 0x80073D02, The package could not be installed because resources it
modifies are currently in use.
error 0x80004004: Unable to install because the following apps need to be closed
Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_cw5n1h2txyewy!CortanaUI.
NOTE: For additional information, look for [ActivityId] 2f7c4f34-6b07-0003-3254-7c2f076bd101 in the Event Log or use
the command line Get-AppxLog -ActivityID 2f7c4f34-6b07-0003-3254-7c2f076bd101
At line:1 char:38
+ ...  | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.I ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (C:\Windows\Syst...ppXManifest.xml:String) [Add-AppxPackage], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DeploymentError,Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands.AddAppxPackageCommand
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It clearly says 'Unable to install because the following apps need to be closed' and points to Cortana, so head to Task Manager and close it, then retry

Comment: I use Windows 10 enterprise 2015 Cortana LTSB it does not support so I can not turn off